# Macro expansion problems when passing parameters

Tags: c++

Can't figure out what's going on with this one. This is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
class WhatThe
{
 public:
  WhatThe(std::string Type, int channel) {}
  ~WhatThe() {}

  void Doitnow() {}
};

#define DO_SOMETHING_TEST1 WhatThe("TEST1", channel)
#define DO_SOMETHING_TEST2 WhatThe("TEST2", channel)

#define DO_IT(type, channel) \
        DO_SOMETHING_##type.Doitnow()
```

then calling

```
DO_IT(TEST1,1);
```

I get an -- error: ‘channel’ was not declared in this scope

Is what I have even possible to do, can you have macros within macros and pass a parameter through them?  I would have thought that

```
DO_SOMETHING_##type.Doitnow()
```

would end up being expanded to

```
WhatThe("TEST1", 1).DoitNow()
```

Comment: what exactly is it you are trying to achieve (part from making the code  a pain to debug)?

Comment: I'm just trying to learn a bit more about macro expansion, the structure came from g2log [link](https://sites.google.com/site/kjellhedstrom2/g2log-efficient-background-io-processign-with-c11) in g2log.h.  I'm sure he has some good reasons for doing it.

Comment: Note that many (if not all) compilers provide an option to write the result of the preprocessor into a file. For example in Visual Studio you find this in project properties / Configuration Properties / C/C++ / Preprocessor / Preprocess to a File. And for gcc and g++ it's the -E option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define DO_SOMETHING_TEST1(channel) WhatThe("TEST1", channel)
#define DO_SOMETHING_TEST2(channel) WhatThe("TEST2", channel)

#define DO_IT(type, channel) \
        DO_SOMETHING_##type(channel).Doitnow()
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked, thought I tried exactly that about 10 mins ago, must need to take a break from the screen for a while

Answer (score -1):

```
#define TEST "TEST1"
#define CHANNEL 1

WhatThe(TEST, CHANNEL).DoitNow()
```

This has the same amount of code to change whenever you want to do a different TEST or CHANNEL, as your proposed solution. To do a different test, just change the defines.

To combine parameters, do this:

```
#ifdef TEST1_CHANNEL1
    #define TEST "TEST1"
    #define CHANNEL 1
#endif

#ifdef TEST1_CHANNEL2
    #define TEST "TEST1"
    #define CHANNEL 2
#endif

...
```

Comment: If for every different "test", we have to change the #defines, then is it not better to just pass the parameter in WhatThe Class ? This solution will not solve or ease the code.

Comment: Even if it doesn't reduce code, it still improves readability by separating the "testing" part from the actual code. I've also edited my answer to reflect one way to combine parameters.

Comment: And if I have n numbers of channels, would you prefer to use n numbers of define's for both TEST1 and TEST2 and suppose if I have to add TEST3 in future then again n definitions and so on?